# React Date Picker in Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux-form, react-datepicker

I am using redux form to design a user profile. In that profile I want to send user's date of birth to the redux store. In that case I am writing a function as below for date picker component.

```
const renderBirthday = ({
  input,
  label,
  meta: { touched, error },
  ...custom
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker
        {...input}
        dateForm="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
        selected={input.value ? moment(input.value) : null}
        onChange={date => input.onChange(moment(date).format("YYYY/MM/DD"))}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the Field in the redux form.

```
        <Field
            component={renderBirthday}
            name="dateOfBirth"

          />
```

Although the date gets set to the field, it can't be sent to the redux store. Can someone help me for solving this matter?

Comment: This code looks ok actually. If your date wasn't set in redux, it would not be set on the field, the change would not reflect there.

Comment: @Kox Instead of using a seperate customized component for Date Picker, I tried upon 
       <DatePicker
                    selected={this.state.dateOfBirth}
                    onChange={this.handleDobChange}
                    dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd h:mm aa"
                    component="input"
                    name="dateOfBirth"
                  />
Then it was working fine. But when I reset the field I can't directly call upon "reset " API . Do you have any suggession for this?

Comment: not sure if I follow. You're adding `component` and `name` props to `<Datepicker />`?